# Retrieve previously connected device from another phone - BLE swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I need functionality like user is pairing to an device. And he/she should be able to retrieve that device from any iOS mobile device. i.e., without connecting.

So I have saved the id which is getting at the time of connection success and saves the same in server.

But when user is trying to login from another device, the `retrievePeripherals` is returning null array. Because the id was device specific.

### Edit

As Paulw said in comments its great to make connection in background. So is there any way to know any details about my previously connected BLE device from this saved identifier.

Like

During first connection :
`phone uuid + device characteristics = identifier // + refers to some internal operations done by OS`

So in reverse can I do

`identifier - phone uuid = device characteristics`

Comment: You will need to discover the peripheral on each iOS device. You cannot simply share the identifier.  You could have a fixed identifier which is available via a characteristic. Each iOS device would then need to connect to the discovered device and read this characteristic to determine if it is the peripheral it is looking for.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. But in an android phone they can. Is there any way to hide this reconnection effort from user? By splitting uuid or something from device and performing scan -> connect next time

Comment: There is no reason that the discovery, connection and interrogation of potential devices needs to be visible to the user.

Comment: So I could know the previous device from identifier right. I have many BLE devices which is interacting with device each time. So can I split any character of device from this identifier from another device

Comment: first time (phone uuid + device characteristics = identifier) so in reverse can I do (identifier - phone uuid = device characteristics) ?

Comment: Once a given iOS device has connected to your peripheral it can save the identifier but the first time it will need to scan for all peripherals ad erising your service, connect and interrogate the peripheral to see if it is the one it is interested in.

Comment: Yes exactly you're there